# Google indexing urls that doesn´t exist - htaccess problem?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I run a site with 3 PHP files.

- index.php
- offers.php
- send.php

I use this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?secure/(.*) https://example.com$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Google keeps indexing URLs that doesn´t exist like:

https://example.com/offers.php/**ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/li**

https://example.com/**ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/li**

https://example.com/send.php/**ddlf/**

Url :

https://example.com/send.php/ddlf/ is showing the content of https://example.com/send.php
and it doesn´t make sense...

I need only `index.php`, `offers.php` and `send.php` indexed.

I tried a lot of changes last 3 months and google bot still keeps crawling those URLs that doesn´t exist in my site structure. `Robots.txt` seems not to help.

Any idea?

Comment: You only need to turn `RewriteEngine On` Once, probably not the issue but

Comment: But do those links exist on the page

Comment: @RiggsFolly is on.

Comment: They don´t exists.If i load those i see same content as original.(double content)

Comment: @Clickhero if they don't exists, then return HTTP404 (or maybe HTTP410). When you return same content (assuming with HTTP200) Google bot really can distinguish between exists or not.

Comment: @rkosegi i can even write example.com/something.php/asdas and it shows my index site broken but with content.

Comment: How can i redirect all files from  a subdirectory of a directory like example.com/index.php/here to example.com/index.php?

Comment: `/something.php/asdas` works due to the PATH_INFO functionality, try and explicitly disable that - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Comment: Google doesn’t tend to make up URLs on its own though. If something like `/offers.php/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/li` gets requested, then that pretty much looks like the resolution of a relative URL somewhere went wrong, and that would most likely be due to something in your code then.